# How to skip first child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```html
<div id="main">    
  <p> one </p>    
  <p> two </p>
  <p> three </p>
  <p> four </p>
  <p> five </p>
<div>
```

I don't want to apply css on first `<p>One</p>`

```
p {color:red}
```

I need just opposite of `:first-child`.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

With [the negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```
p:not(:first-child) { color: red; }
```

Browser support is [very strong](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot) now, but alternatives include:

```
p { color: red; }
p:first-child { color: black; }
```

and:

```
* + p { color: red; }
```

Comment: For the second solution, I would suggest using `p:first-child{ color:inherit; }` instead of `p:first-child{ color:black; }` so it works with any preset color.

Answer (score 23):

Quentin's `:not()` solution works great for modern browsers:

```
p:not(:first-child) { color: red; }
```

His alternative for older browsers also works well, except it makes use of an overriding rule for the first child. It's not *required*, however...

You can simply use a sibling selector to apply the same rule as the one above, without the need to override it for `p:first-child`. Either one of these rules will work:

- The [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), which matches any `p` that comes directly after a `p`:

  ```
  p + p { color: red; }
  ```
- The [general sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), which matches any `p` that comes anywhere after a `p`:

  ```
  p ~ p { color: red; }
  ```

Both combinators work identically here; the subtle differences between them only apply when you have other elements in the mix. Refer to the links provided for details.

Answer (score 21):

I think `:nth-child()` will do the trick.

```
p:nth-child(n+2){
  background-color:red;
}
```

This styles all of the `p` tags except for the first because it starts on the 2nd child. You could then style the first `p` tag separately with `p:first-child`.

Answer (score 8):

Works everytime and doesn't need undoing:

```
p + p {
  /* do 15 special things */
}
```

It takes every P that was preceded by a P. Don't set a property to undo it later. You should only add, if you can help it, not subtract.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use "tilde" ( ~ ) operator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
    p ~ p {
        background:#ff0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>The first paragraph.</p>
    <p>The second paragraph.</p>
    <p>The third paragraph.</p>
    <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/RpfLa/344/

Did a quick test on FF 17, Chrome 23, Safari 5.1, IE9, IE1-8 on compaitbility mode

Comment: Not very efficient, because the 6th `P` is matched 5 times.

Comment: This works for classes, skipping 1st class occurrence, since the rule .classX ~ .classX is matched on 2nd(preceded by 1st), 3rd(preceded by 2nd) etc.