# Excluding first element in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to skip first child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855679/how-to-skip-first-child)

I have a `ul` with 4 `li` in it:

```
<div id="someid">
    <ul>
       <li>1st</li>
       <li>2nd</li>
       <li>3rd</li>
       <li>4th</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm setting a style for these `li` elements:

```
#someid ul li{
      font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now I want exclude the first `li`.  How can I do it?

Comment: In theory I agree that this should be closed as an exact duplicate, but there is a better cross browser solution than the one given in the linked question. I think it would have been in the interest of StackOverflow to leave it open so other answers can be given.

Comment: @My Head Hurts : `li+li`? Please post the answer in the linked topic. Though it's OK with his example but not with the title of his question.

Comment: @My Head Hurts: I posted it as a comment. Should I turn it into an answer?

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I think that would be a good idea

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks. You worded better than I could ever do.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
#someid ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
      font-weight: bold;
}
```

or if that doesn't work in ancient browsers:

```
#someid ul li {
      font-weight: bold;
}
#someid ul li:first-child {
      font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-child) selector:

```
#someid ul li:first-child { 
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: about your comment on W3Schools in a deleted question: http://w3fools.com/ should answer your question :)