# How to exclude the first td when selecting a tr? CSS, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I have this script that changes `background-color` for a table's `tr` when clicked:

```
<script>
  $('#reviews').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
  })
</script>
```

It works fine. However, I'd like to exclude the first `td` of the `tr`. So, when the user clicks on the first `td` nothing happens. How to exclude it?

Tried this:

```
<script>
  $('#reviews').on('click', 'tbody tr:not(:first-of-type)', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
  })
</script>
```

But it still highlight the entire row when clicking on the first `td`.

Comment: answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977816/excluding-first-element-in-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks. But I tried it, same issue.

Comment: That answer is targeting the tds specifically.  Your delegate child selector is targeting the trs.  So they are different in that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exclude the first `tr` not `td` of each line. If I understand your goals correctly, it should looks something like this:

```
  $('#reviews').on('click', 'tbody tr td:not( :first-of-type )', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
  })
```

[Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/196651/)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to exclude first tr, but mentioned you wanted first td excluded.

try like this

```
$('#reviews').on('click', 'tbody > tr', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().find('td:not(:first-of-type)').addClass('highlight');
    $('table#reviews tr > td:not(:first-of-type).highlight').removeClass('highlight');
})
```